# i want to load the different story boards when my application launched

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Previously my project has worked with iPhone 4 and iPhone 5 storyboards but I want to add a storyboard for iPhone 6.

I included some logic in the AppDelegate to check the resolution like this:

```
printf("\nDetected Resolution : %d x %d\n\n",(int)[[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeBounds].size.width,(int)[[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeBounds].size.height);
```

1334 for iPhone 6, 1136 for iPhone 5 and 960 for iPhone 4.

After running the application with the iPhone 6 simulator it is using the iPhone 5 storyboard and the result is:

Detected Resolution : 640 x 1136

But I want it like this:

Detected Resolution : 750 x 1334 when the application is launched.

Can anyone tell me why it is doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add launch image to let iOS to know The app is designed for iPhone 6
[image]

check my detail answer from here

[iPhone 6 a different storyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855055/iphone-6-a-different-storyboard/26084863#26084863)

Comment: thanks for the solution. i was new new to the ios8 thats why i dont know to change the app launch images.

Comment: Dont worry about being inexperience. This is why there is a community here to help each other. Here is a good read for you.  http://matthewpalmer.net/blog/2014/09/10/iphone-6-plus-launch-image-adaptive-mode/

Comment: yes i had seen it now, previously idont know abt that, i already told u that iam new to the community & ios filed. once again thans for that.